# CFQuery Giving Odd Internal Server 500 Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion, cfquery

```
<cfif structKeyExists(url, 'results')>
   <cfquery datasource="UIAAWeb" name="fullQuery"> 
       SELECT *
       FROM BusinessDirectory
       ORDER BY businessname
   </cfquery> 
<cfelse>
   <cfquery datasource="UIAAWeb" name="BusinessQuery">
       SELECT *
       FROM   BusinessDirectory
       WHERE 
       <!--- Matches Exact Last Name if Match Radio is selected --->
       <cfif #form.match# is "yes"> 
          businessname = '#form.keyword#' 
       </cfif> 
       <!--- Matches Last Names Starting with user inputted letter --->
       <cfif (#match# is "no") AND (#form.keyword# neq "")> 
           businessname LIKE '#form.keyword#%' 
       </cfif>
       <!--- Gets all award types from selected field of awards --->
       <cfif #form.industry# neq "*"> 
           AND industry IN ('#form.industry#')
       </cfif>

       <!--- Matches Exact Last Name if Match Radio is selected --->
       <cfif #form.match1# is "yes"> 
           AND city = '#form.city#' 
       </cfif> 
       <!--- Matches Last Names Starting with user inputted letter --->
       <cfif (#match1# is "no") AND (#form.city# neq " ")> 
           AND city LIKE '#form.city#%' 
       </cfif>

       <!--- Gets all award types from selected field of awards --->
       <cfif #form.state# neq "*"> 
           state IN ('#form.state#')
       </cfif>

       <!--- Gets all award types from selected field of awards --->
       <cfif #form.country# neq "*"> 
           country IN ('#form.country#')
       </cfif>

    ORDER BY #sort#
</cfquery>
```

I am trying to write a search query like so, however when I keep executing the search page I get internal server error 500:

> Element CITY is undefined in FORM. The specific sequence of files
>   included or processed is:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\business\search\search_results.cfm, line: 139

If I remove `city` from all areas of the query  I get this error:

> Error Executing Database Query.Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'AND'. The specific sequence of files included or processed is:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\business\search\search_results.cfm, line: 146

And if I remove the `AND` from everywhere I get this error

> Error Executing Database Query.Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'industry'. The specific sequence of files included or processed is:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\business\search\search_results.cfm, line: 146

What am I doing incorrectly/how do I fix this? I have checked and rechecked my form and everything is defined correctly.

[searchform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nflA2.jpg)

So I am trying to get it to search through all of these but to ignore a field if one is ommitted? I can't seem to get it to leave them out if a field is omitted.

Thanks!

Comment: Couple tips 1. RE: *Element CITY is undefined* Radio buttons only exist if they checked.  Either verify it exists first OR define a default with `cfparam` 2. **Never** use raw client supplied values in a query. Always use `cfqueryparam` 3. No need for pound signs in the `cfif` statements. 4. The strings "Yes/no" will be evaluated as boolean, ie `true/false`. So assuming the field is defined, instead of writing `<cfif #form.match# is "yes">` just use `<cfif form.match>`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a problem in dynamically generating SQL `WHERE` clause.

Looks like you've got a bare `WHERE` keyword. If there isn't a condition on `businessname`, the **`businessname = 'val'`** part isn't going to be included in the SQL text. So the generated SQL will be invalid.

If there's no condition on `businessname`, but there is one on `industry`, the code is going to generate an invalid SQL construct, like this:

```
WHERE AND industry = 'someval'
      ^^^
```

(In that construct, the token `AND` is  unexpected keyword. MySQL isn't expecting that.)

If we modify the code to remove the `AND` keyword to fix that problem, we create another problem. When when it executes and there is a condition on `businessname`, the code will generate an invalid SQL construct that looks like this (because we removed the `AND` keyword):

```
WHERE businessname = 'val' industry = 'someval'
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

(In that construct, when MySQL encounters `industry`, it's expecting to find a keyword token such as `AND`.

---

---

To resolve this problem, I recommend a code pattern like this:

Start with query text ending with **`" WHERE 1=1"`**.

This doesn't really affect the query, since the condition will always evaluate to TRUE. (The optimizer will just throw it out.) We're only including that so that it makes the rest of our code simpler.

Later in code, when we need to append a predicate (condition) onto the `WHERE` clause, we just use the **`AND`** keyword. (And we remember to include the required white space before the keyword).)  We append:

```
 " AND somecol = 'somevalue'"
```

And we follow that same pattern for each search condition we might need to add to the `WHERE` clause.

The net result is that we get a valid `WHERE` clause, even if we don't add any conditions.

If we do add predicates (search conditions), our code doesn't need to be concerned about whether the `WHERE` keyword has already been included in the statement or not.  The first predicate being added would need to use the `WHERE` keyword instead of `AND`. And we would need to keep track of that. The first condition we append would need the `WHERE` keyword, the subsequent conditions would need an `AND`.

Since there's multiple conditional checks on whether a predicate is going to be appended to the statement, we would need to check everytime we want to append to the statement. We'd need to ask "have we started the `WHERE` clause yet?", or "is this the first condition in the `WHERE` clause?"

By having the statement include **`WHERE 1=1`**, we make the job a little easier. We don't need to keep track of whether or not we've added the `WHERE` keyword yet.

End result of the pattern, we get a slightly funkier looking SQL statement (with the trivial `1=1` condition). But the flip side is that we get slightly simpler code.

---

Following that pattern, we'd expect our code to generate SQL statements like this:

With no search conditions added to the statement:

```
  WHERE 1=1
```

which is valid.

With a search condition on `city`...

```
  WHERE 1=1 AND city = 'somevalue'
```

again, this is valid.

With a search condition on `industry`...

```
  WHERE 1=1 AND industry = 'somevalue'
```

With search conditions on both `city` and `industry`

```
  WHERE 1=1 AND city = 'somevalue' AND industry = 'somevalue'
```

and so on.

Comment: so i need multiple where statements?

Comment: Uhhhhmmmm, no. I've edited the answer to indicate what I think is happening with your code, what is wrong with the SQL that is being generated. The fix for your code is to add "`1=1`" after the `WHERE` keyword. And then add "`AND`" before `businessname`. (I think there may be some other problems with the code, like generating the `IN` list.)  But I'm guessing that the `WHERE 1=1` pattern, always appending `AND condition`, will fix the problem you are reporting.

Comment: *there may be some other problems with the code, like generating the IN list* Yep. Those will not work as expected if the variables, like `#form.state#`, contain multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use `<cfqueryparam>` because

1. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection
2. It can do lists of values.

   ```
   ...
   WHERE 1= 1

   <!--- Matches Exact Last Name if Match Radio is selected --->
   <cfif form.match is "yes"> 
      AND businessname = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.keyword#"> 
   </cfif> 
   <!--- Matches Last Names Starting with user inputted letter --->
   <cfif (form.match is "no") AND (form.keyword neq "")> 
       AND businessname LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.keyword#%"> 
   </cfif>
   <!--- Gets all award types from selected field of awards --->
   <cfif form.industry neq "*"> 
      AND industry IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#form.industry#" list="yes">)
   </cfif>

   ...
   ```

Note that the last `cfqueryparam` has `list="yes"`

Comment: @Jacob Langreck - You also need to protect the `ORDER BY #sort#` clause (which is wide open to sql injection). However, that *cannot* be done with cfqueryparam.

Comment: How can I get this to search by multiple fields with not all fields being required am I on the right track? I am using OR instead of and but it brings out all results still.

Comment: That is a very open ended question. There are often more than one way to program something. As a coding standard I try to avoid `<cfif>` inside of `<cfquery>`. But the current approach will work.

Comment: So my search is working but if I type in say Cerner into the business field and leave all other fields blank it displays all of the companies in the search instead of if I leave one field blank to just omit it from the search?

Ill add a photo of my search form quick

Comment: Ok I added a little more to the description underneath the form

Comment: You should make this a different question as it is a different topic. SO allows you to have an unlimited number of questions. Stackexchange Code Review may also be useful

Comment: @Jacob - S.O. is different than a discussion forum: one question per thread.  Your new/updated question is a little too broad to be a good fit. Tip: Building dynamic queries is an *iterative* process: Add a *single* filter. Verify it works as expected. Lather, rinse, repeat. Trying to write everything once, and hoping for the best, usually does not work ;-) Take a step back and start with a clean slate. Start by testing *one* of filters.  Enable full debugging and so you can review and verify the generated SQL statement is correct. Get a single filter working first. Then move to the next.

Comment: ... if you run into problems with the *single* filter test, open a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob, if you are still looking for a solution for this, then just like everyone has suggested try this.

```
<!--- DUMP FORM VALUES TO SEE WHAT IS BEING RETURNED --->
<CFDUMP VAR="#FORM#">

<cfif structKeyExists(url, 'results')>
   <cfquery datasource="UIAAWeb" name="fullQuery"> 
       SELECT *
       FROM BusinessDirectory
       ORDER BY businessname
   </cfquery> 
<cfelse>
   <cfquery datasource="UIAAWeb" name="BusinessQuery">
       SELECT *
       FROM   BusinessDirectory
       WHERE 
              1 = 1
       <!--- Matches Exact Last Name if Match Radio is selected --->
       <cfif #form.match# is "yes"> 
          AND businessname = '#form.keyword#' 
       </cfif> 
       <!--- Matches Last Names Starting with user inputted letter --->
       <cfif (#match# is "no") AND (#form.keyword# neq "")> 
          AND businessname LIKE '#form.keyword#%' 
       </cfif>
       <!--- Gets all award types from selected field of awards --->
       <cfif #form.industry# neq "*"> 
           AND industry IN ('#form.industry#')
       </cfif>


    ORDER BY #sort#
</cfquery>
```

Then you can then add other form elements to the query like city , address or other form entries. Baby steps, one step at a time.

Also, cfqueryparam suggestion was spot on. Didnt know you could do list = "yes". Thats a great tip. :-)